# Exposing a model without any routes

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm trying to do pretty much what is explained in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#expose-a-model-without-any-routes. To stick to that example, I have:

- An API resource `Place` with full CRUD functionality
- Another model `Weather` that represents the weather of a place
  and I want to have a `GET /places/{id}/weather` endpoint to get the weather of a specific place.

The solutions that I came up with and the problems I see in them

- Having an API Platform independent controller/route that handles this

  - The route is not showing up in the OpenAPI documentation (could implement this myself of course)
  - I don't benefit from the built-in serialization features and have to implement this myself
- Making `Weather` a resource and creating it via custom Controller as done in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#expose-a-model-without-any-routes

  - `Weather` needs an ID to work (right?)
  - Referencing a non-existant Controller and removing endpoints from the OpenAPI documentation but NOT their routes feels very hacky to me
- Making `Weather` a subresource

  - A `weather` property/reference in my `Place` resource is incorrect / not needed
  - `Weather` needs an ID again which is not wanted
- Making `Weather` a dedicated API resource and using a custom Controller or DataProvider with the places ID

  - I'm kind of misusing the `Place` ID for `Weather`
- Making `Weather` a custom representation / output / DTO of `Place` with a custom route and a custom Controller

  - `Weather` is not a `Place`

I currently went with the last solution because I could get rid of the ID in `Weather` and only needed a text adaption in the OpenAPI documentation. The annotation that I'm using in `Place` is looking like the following

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get",
 *         "delete",
 *         "put",
 *         "patch",
 *         "get_weather"={
 *             "method"="GET",
 *             "path"="/places/{id}/weather",
 *             "controller"=WeatherController::class,
 *             "output"=Weather::class
 *         }
 *     },
 * )
```

But there must be a better solution for this, right? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I think your solution is OK. I do not understand why you think the output of a GET operation must be a representation of the resource. I think it can be anything that makes sense (is meaningfull in the real world you are modeling) for an operation that makes sense in the context of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Hi create a config yaml file in api_platform configuration with content like

```
Weather:
  shortName: 'Weather'

  attributes:
    output: 'WeatherModel'

  collectionOperations: [] 
  itemOperations: []
```