# Best practice for custom REST actions with API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

[This top-ranking Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077229/restful-password-reset) from 10 years ago suggests using `POST /users/:user_id/reset_password` to initiate a password reset.

I know the API platform [recommends against using custom operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers). The docs page for the [Symfony Messenger integration](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/messenger) uses a `ResetPasswordRequest` entity (with a username field). That makes sense to me.

Say I have a `User` and `Notification` entity and maybe a joined `UserNotification` (with a `hasRead`) entity as well. I want to expose an endpoint on my API to mark all the notifications older than a month as read. So I might make a `ClearOldNotification` entity, again with a username field.

Another example might be I want a report showing `Customers` that haven't been contacted due to some criteria. So I want to join the tables in the server and return a custom JSON data object. Again I could make a `CustomerNoContact` entity.

The issue I see is that I now have a distinction between *pure* entities, like a `User` or `Product`, as opposed to these *service* type entities.

- Is this method of making individual entities classes for actions the recommended, best practice for Symfony and API Platform?
- Should I be name-spacing (or something) these entities differently within my app to distinguish them?
- I could imagine on a really large and complex application you could have hundreds of these *service* entities, compared to the *pure* entities. Is that expected or desired?
- Can anyone recommend some good resources on this pattern?

Comment: IMHO service type Entities are workarounds for limitations imposed by Api Platform. But other solution are available: As suggested in the Design Considerations [a POPO can be used as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744246/operation-without-entity). And/or a [DTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847821/exposing-a-model-without-any-routes) or [a view model](https://github.com/metaclass-nl/tutorial-api-platform/blob/chapter9-api) as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a best practice for two different use cases. Let's break it down:

### ClearOldNotification

I think you've already found the solution: using Messenger. As you've read, there is an example in the documentation for this use case:

```
#[ApiResource(collectionOperations: [
        "post", "get", "delete",
        "reset_password" => ["status" => 202, "messenger" => "input", "input" => ResetPasswordRequest::class, "output" => false, "method" => "POST", "path" => "/users/reset_password"]
    ]
)]
final class User
{
}
```

The `ResetPasswordRequest` class is a [Data Transfer Object (DTO)](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/). In your `ResetPasswordRequestHandler` you should inject the service that is responsible for resetting the password and sending an email.

### CustomerNoContact

This could be a [Custom (Doctrine ORM) Filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters).